# System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Insufficient system storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I use [System.Net.Mail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail(v=vs.110).aspx) `Namespace` in c# for send email messages from server.

But if only one address email of mailing list is satured to messages and can't receive more messages I have this error:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Insufficient system storage. The server
>   response was: 4.3.1 Insufficient system resources

I have read much tips on google without success, because this error can happen when:

1. The exchange server is out of disk space.
2. The recipient mailbox is out of disk space.

And I can't check e-mail server status.

How to do resolve this ?

Please help me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    s.Send(m);

} catch (SmtpException ex) {
    if (ex.StatusCode == SmtpStatusCode.InsufficientStorage) {
        //Send again to ensure this email gets sent 
        s.Send(m);
    } else {
        //Handle other SMTP errors here. 
        Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

[Reference link](http://www.studiocoast.com.au/knowledgebase/article-112-aspnet-insufficient-system-storage-error-when-using-smtpclient.aspx)